# How do you find the minimum distance between two skew planes?

Tags: optimization

I know how to find the minimum distance between 2 skew lines. Does that help me with skew planes?

Comment: No. Two "skew" planes in a 3D space always collide...

Comment: It would also help to know in what dimension we are talking about.  If it is as simple as being in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the two planes are parallel and you can pick any point from one plane and find the point on the other which is closest.  If it is in $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 4}$ however, the process becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: It's 4 dimensional thinking and they are 2 skew planes. A method is supposed to be constructing in order to find the minimum distance between 2 skew planes

Comment: Wikipedia answers this question very clear.